# How can I use UTType for comparing in a condition in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am getting a folder url from user and then looking to find any mp3 files in that folder, the question itself in title and me just looking to use **UTType** in process.

As you can see I took all steps in codes just need last step in **isMP3** function to finish the puzzle. So how can I use a path or URL and fining out the UTType of it and using it for comparing.

Also in my approach Xcode gave an error and says:

> Cannot find 'UTType' in scope

Not sure why I have this error, normally it should Not be case, because it is type defined by Apple.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileImporterIsPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Select your Folder") { fileImporterIsPresented = true }
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $fileImporterIsPresented, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], allowsMultipleSelection: false, onCompletion: { result in
                
                switch result {
                case .success(let urls):
                    
                    if let unwrappedURL: URL = urls.first {
                        
                        if let contents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: unwrappedURL.path) {
                            
                            contents.forEach { item in
                                if isMP3(path: unwrappedURL.path + "/" + item) {
                                    print(item)
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error selecting file \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
            })
        
    }
}


func isMP3(path: String) -> Bool {
    // trying use UTType here
    if URL(fileURLWithPath: path).??? == UTType.mp3 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use UTType you have to import explicit package

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
```

it can be something like

```
func isMP3(path: String) -> Bool {
    if let type = UTType(filenameExtension: URL(fileURLWithPath: path).pathExtension), type == UTType.mp3 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: why not simply `UTType(filenameExtension: URL(fileURLWithPath: path).pathExtension) == .mp3`?

Comment: I had this `Cannot find type 'UTType' in scope` problem using `NSItemProvider`. I even used the UTType in a SwiftUI method 2 lines above `.onDrop(of: [.fileURL], isTargeted: nil, perform:...)`. When I referenced `UTType` in the perform function,  I got the scope issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that uses [URLResourceValues.contentType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues/3551434-contenttype) with a fallback to [UTType(filenameExtension:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551510-init):

```swift
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

func isMP3(path: String) -> Bool {
    if let contentType = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).contentType,
       contentType.conforms(to: .mp3)
    {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}

extension URL {
    var contentType: UTType? {
        if let resourceValues = try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.contentTypeKey]),
           let contentType = resourceValues.contentType {
            return contentType
        } else if let contentType = UTType(filenameExtension: pathExtension) {
            return contentType
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }    
}
```